# Scaling an editor canvas

Tags: racket

I'm playing around with racket and planning to implement a node editor (if there is already one PLEASE let me know!). The main blackboard is a pasteboard% in an editor canvas% and now I'm dealing with the zooming functionality.
Basically I can set the scale of the drawing context to get it scaled:

`;; c is my editor-canvas%
(send (send c get-dc) set-scale 2 2)`

However this only scales the drawing calls, but the event coordinates are unchanged so they are not dispatched correctly.

I'm looking for some method to transform the coordinate of all events in the dispatching process but currently haven't find anything useful. Is there any way to place a "transformer" in the dispatch process? Or is there some other solution to scale the whole canvas and get the event dispatching correct?

Comment: You can use `(send dc get-transformation)` to get the transformation you need. (not quite what you ask for - but it might be help)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I think I almost figure out a solution (just my current best solution).

I use `(send (send c get-dc) set-scale 2 2)` to adjust display scale. Then I use `pasteboard%`'s `interactive-adjust-mouse`, 
`interactive-adjust-move`, and
`interactive-adjust-resize` to override the coordinates. The Racket GUI framework do not provide a general way to manipulate events in the dispatch process, but `pasteboard%` provides those method for changing coordinate of the events, and it seems to work.

On the other hand, for arbitrary modification on the events, I find it useful to override the widgets' `on-event` method and call `(super on-event modified-events)` or manually dispatch them to children if you want to change dispatching order, etc.